# merge several lines in a txt based on the beginning of the first column

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a txt file1 which has four columns:

```
Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8 1 0 3
Staphylococcus_aureus_subsp_aureus<0.8 1 2 0
Staphylococcus_aureus_subsp_aureus_S228<0.8 2 0 2
```

I want generate an output txt file2 looks like:

```
Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8 4 2 5
```

explanation: the first column has the same beginning "Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8" and i want to add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th columns.

I'm thinking awk, sed, perl, or python.

any ideas?

Comment: What logic is used to generate the first column in the output (`Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8`)?

Answer (score 2):

To output the sum total columns 2-4, you could use awk:

```
awk '{ col2+=$2; col3+=$3; col4+=$4 } END { printf "%d %d %d\n", col2, col3, col4 }' file1 > file2
```

Update your post to explain the logic for generating column 1 in the output and we can see how to best incorporate that part into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

for one sum

```
$ awk 'NR==1          {f1=$1; split($1,ks,"<"); k=ks[1]} 
       index($1,k)==1 {f2+=$2; f3+=$3; f4+=$4} 
       END            {print f1,f2,f3,f4}' file

Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8 4 2 5
```

grab the key from first line, add the fields and at the end print the result.

Comment: thx, right, the intention was `index`, somehow ended up `match`

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution:

```sh
tac file1 | while read c1 c2 c3 c4; do echo $c1 $((A+=c2)) $((B+=c3)) $((C+=c4)) > file2; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -E ':a;N;/^([^<]+)<(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)\n\1\S+\2 (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)$/s//printf "%s<%s %s %s %s" \1 \2 $((\3+\6)) $((\4+\7)) $((\5+\8))/e;$!ta;P;D' file
```

Use pattern matching and back references to accumulate the last 3 fields of each line with a common key.

N.B. The use of the `e` flag on the substitution command to replace the pattern space by a `printf` command which when evaluated dynamically updates the accumulated values.

Answer (score -1):

Perl solution:

```
$ perl -ne '@c=split; $k=$c[0] if $.==1; $c1+=$c[1]; $c2+=$c[2]; $c3+=$c[3]; }{ print "$k $c1 $c2 $c3\n"' file1
Staphylococcus_aureus<0.8 4 2 5
```

The `$k` key is just grabbed from the first column of the first line (when `$.==1`)

Otherwise this is the awk solution with the column indices starting at zero

The incrementing variables could be conditionally incremented for lines starting with some part of $k... but as said, it's not clear what you want to do there.